# discord.py: invoking command with no context

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a listener waiting for someone to join a specific voice channel, when they do I would like it to run another command on the bot. The issue I have is that I cannot invoke another command `ctx.invoke(play, arg)` because I have no message context.

I am wondering if there is another way of invoking a command or if I could obtain context from elsewhere, as the command being run will function the same regardless of context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking command inside command discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64507433/invoking-command-inside-command-discord-py). Note that if you do not need the context, you still need to pass something in place of the context (i.e. you can pass `...` or `None`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the following:

```
@bot.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  if not before.channel and after.channel and not member.bot:
    if after.channel.id == [YOUR_CHANNEL_ID]:
```

Comment: I have no issue with this part, I already have this in place. The issue I have is with invoking the second command, as I have no message context.

Comment: That's true, my bad, didn't read it with much attention. I'll check again and update my answer if there are still no other answers

Comment: I think you can't get a context object in this case, so you could make a function with the functionality you want, and call it on your "play" command and also on the event.